Swift (macOS) hook into and intercept notifications, and customize delivery
I’m interested in building a utility for macOS that allows deeper customization of notifications from other apps that they might not offer the granularity of. For this I need to be able to hook into notifications, intercept them, read their content, and decide whether to show them, show without sound, suppress them (eg put in notifications center without playing).
With swift, is it possible to hook into this level of global controls of notifications?

There are no APIs for manipulating other processes' notifications (in Swift or otherwise); you'd need to inject code into whatever system process is responsible for displaying notifications, and override its functionality. This is fairly invasive and would require disabling SIP for security reasons. How to do this in Swift specifically would depend on the exact method of injection and how you'd want to intercept the notifications.

Gotcha, thank you!
